# How to access controller in URL instead of partial view's controller

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a layout view, inside the layout view I call

```
@Html.Action("ToolBarAction", "ToolBarController")
```

Inside the view that ToolBarAction returns, I want to get the controller in the URL, but when I call

```
ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue;
```

..I get "ToolBarController"

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't the views lack any reason to know anything about which controller is invoking them?  I'm not really judging this as "wrong", it just has a funny smell to it.

Comment: I highlight the toolbar icon depending on which page is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try?

<strike>`ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]`</strike>

**UPDATE**

```
ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
```